# Python: How to dynamically set inner class class variable

Tags: python, peewee

I am working with peewee and SQLite on a project. I have two files:

file1.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = Thing()
```

file2.py

```
DB_FILENAME = 'db_name.db'
DB_FILE_PATH = f'/tmp/{DB_FILENAME}'
db = SqliteDatabase(DB_FILE_PATH)

class Thing(Model):
    field1 = CharField(primary_key=True)
    field2 = CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

The Thing class needs to be able to write into several different databases so I need a clean way of making DB_FILENAME configurable so that the inner class database field will be initialized to the appropriate name.

The inner Meta class appears to be required and this setup is what is referenced in the documentation (the db declared globally).
Additional Note: This code is being run in AWS Lambda.

EDIT: Working solution in fact did not work.

Comment: See the docs: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#run-time-database-configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function that creates the class, and call it with the environment variable as an argument.

```
# file2.py

def make_model(db_file_name):
    class Thing(Model):
        field1 = CharField(primary_key=True)
        field2 = CharField()

        class Meta:
            database = SqliteDatabase(f'/tmp/{db_file_name}')

    return Thing


# script

from file2 import make_model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = make_model(f'db_name_{os.getenv("SUFFIX")}.db')
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation covers this: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#run-time-database-configuration

```
database = PostgresqlDatabase(None)  # Un-initialized database.

class SomeModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database

....

database_name = input('What is the name of the db? ')
database.init(database_name, host='localhost', user='postgres')
```

Comment: I actually found this out later myself but the original answer does apply to the question as it was written even though the question was the result of not knowing this initially.

Comment: Closing over your models is fine, but may cause issues when the closed-over model classes are required elsewhere in a codebase at import-time (as opposed to run-time). That is why Peewee provides the facilities I mentioned in my comment.